# Query to update multi column duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle11g, duplicates, constraints

I am about to apply a 3-column (B_ACCT_UID, B_EXT_ID, B_CAMPAIGN_GUID) unique constraint on my db. 'none' values for B_EXT_ID are not affected. Before doing so I need to update B_EXT_ID rows to remove offenders (append row_id or something like that).

I know how to find them:

```
SELECT B_ACCT_UID, B_EXT_ID, B_CAMPAIGN_GUID, COUNT(*) 
FROM SB_BATCH 
WHERE B_EXT_ID != 'none' 
GROUP BY B_ACCT_UID, B_EXT_ID, B_CAMPAIGN_GUID 
HAVING COUNT(B_EXT_ID) > 1;
```

which prints:

```
B_ACCT_UID B_EXT_ID                                                                                                                         B_CAMPAIGN_GUID                        COUNT(*)
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ----------
3000000010 sto                                                                                                                              setna                                         2 
3000000010 jeden                                                                                                                            pierwsza                                      2 
3000000010 dziewiec                                                                                                                         14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000          3
```

Before trying the update I performed the select query which would get replaced by update.

```
SELECT B_ACCT_UID, B_EXT_ID, B_CAMPAIGN_GUID 
FROM SB_BATCH 
WHERE B_EXT_ID IN (SELECT B_EXT_ID FROM SB_BATCH WHERE B_EXT_ID != 'none'
GROUP BY B_ACCT_UID, B_EXT_ID, B_CAMPAIGN_GUID 
HAVING COUNT(B_EXT_ID) > 1);
```

And got:

```
B_ACCT_UID B_EXT_ID                                                                                                                         B_CAMPAIGN_GUID                    
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
3000000010 sto                                                                                                                              14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000 
3000000010 sto                                                                                                                              setna                                
3000000010 sto                                                                                                                              setna                                
3000000010 jeden                                                                                                                            pierwsza                             
3000000010 jeden                                                                                                                            pierwsza                             
3000000010 jeden                                                                                                                            14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000 
3000000010 dziewiec                                                                                                                         14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000 
3000000010 dziewiec                                                                                                                         14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000 
3000000010 dziewiec                                                                                                                         14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000
```

It's a half working example because it would also update non-offenders like

```
B_ACCT_UID B_EXT_ID                                                                                                                         B_CAMPAIGN_GUID                    
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------
3000000010 sto                                                                                                                              14F8CDEDACE0005C98727464800000000000
```

Can you please help me out to modify the query?

Comment: Which DBMS u r using? Oracle, Mysql?

Comment: It's Oracle, version 11.

Comment: Now what you want to do? Do u want to delete the duplicates? or Update one of the duplicate rows?if so,which column u want to update?

Comment: I've stated it in the question: "Before doing so I need to update B_EXT_ID rows to remove offenders (append row_id or something like that)."

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to -

- use your first query which gives the unique entries for the "offender" records, as you term them, and put them into a temp table (or a table created for temporary purpose).
- Delete ***all*** the offending records in the main table SB_BATCH
- and then again re-insert from the temp table into the table SB_BATCH.

Note - if your IDs are unique and generated using increment/custom logic, delete & re-insert may not preserve them.

If your objective is to remove/delete duplicates in the table, the above will work. But I believe I misundertood your question.